# Windows Annocanda環境で、pipenvでPythonのバージョンを指定できませんでした。なぜでしょうか？

Tags: python, pipenv

## 環境

- Windows 10

```
$ conda --version
conda 4.6.14

$ which python
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.EXE

$ python --version
Python 3.7.3
```

## 実施したこと

`$ pipenv install --python 3.6`でPythonのバージョンを指定してインストールしましたが、`$pipenv run python --version`でバージョンを確認したところ3.7でした。

```
(base) PS>touch Pipfile
(base) PS>pipenv install --python 3.6
Creating a virtualenv for this project…
Pipfile: C:\Users\yuji3\Downloads\pipenv-test\Pipfile
Using C:/Users/yuji3/Anaconda3_5.2.0/python.exe (3.7.2) to create virtualenv…
[==  ] Creating virtual environment...Using base prefix 'C:\\Users\\yuji3\\Anaconda3_5.2.0'
  No LICENSE.txt / LICENSE found in source
New python executable in C:\Users\yuji3\.virtualenvs\pipenv-test-u6cGdScX\Scripts\python.exe
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...
done.
Running virtualenv with interpreter C:/Users/yuji3/Anaconda3_5.2.0/python.exe

Successfully created virtual environment!
Virtualenv location: C:\Users\yuji3\.virtualenvs\pipenv-test-u6cGdScX
Creating a Pipfile for this project…
Pipfile.lock not found, creating…
Locking [dev-packages] dependencies…
Locking [packages] dependencies…
Updated Pipfile.lock (a65489)!
Installing dependencies from Pipfile.lock (a65489)…
  ================================ 0/0 - 00:00:00
To activate this project's virtualenv, run pipenv shell.
Alternatively, run a command inside the virtualenv with pipenv run.
(base) PS>pipenv run python --version
Python 3.7.2
```

## 質問

Pipenvのドキュメントには、`--python`でバージョンを指定できる旨が記載されていました。
https://pipenv-ja.readthedocs.io/ja/translate-ja/basics.html

なぜ、私の環境ではPythonのバージョンを指定できないのでしょうか？
Windowsだからでしょうか？Annacondaを使っているからでしょうか？

## 追記

### Pythonインタプリタの情報

```
(base) PS>pipenv --py
C:\Users\yuji3\.virtualenvs\pipenv-test-u6cGdScX\Scripts\python.exe

(base) PS> pipenv run python -c "import sys; print(sys.executable); print(sys.base_prefix)"
C:\Users\yuji3\.virtualenvs\pipenv-test-u6cGdScX\Scripts\python.exe
C:\Users\yuji3\.virtualenvs\pipenv-test-u6cGdScX
```

#### プロンプトの前の`(base)`

Annaconda Powershell Promptを利用していて、`base`という名前のconda環境を有効にしています。

```
(base) PS>conda info -e
# conda environments:
#
base                  *  C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3
                         C:\Users\yuji3\Anaconda3_5.2.0
                         C:\Users\yuji3\Anaconda3_5.2.0\envs\dj
```

Comment: Python 3.6は既にインストールしてあるんですよね？

Comment: Python3.6インストールしていないです。Pipenvが自動的にやってくれる（インストールしてくれる）と思っていました。

Comment: 「--python — 引数で与えられたPythonインタプリタを使い、」とガイドに書いてあったので、Windows版のAnnocandaにPython 3.6が含まれていなかったのかなぁ、と思ったんですが、うーん、違いますかね。`python3.6 --version`を実行したら、バージョン番号は返りますか？

Comment: pythonコマンドのバージョンは3.7.3です。

Comment: 解決マークが付いていませんが、[Pipenv with Conda?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50546339/9014308) が参考になるかも？

Comment: とは言え、[Anaconda は Environment Isolation Tool (環境分離ツール) ではない](https://qiita.com/t2y/items/dd6d7f9c70ac2b8a79da)、[pyenv、pyenv-virtualenv、venv、Anaconda、Pipenv。私はPipenvを使う。](https://qiita.com/KRiver1/items/c1788e616b77a9bad4dd)、[python, pipenv, pyenv, virtualenv, pip, conda](https://qiita.com/propella/items/247beb6be15bdef66ecc)、[condaとpip：混ぜるな危険](http://onoz000.hatenablog.com/entry/2018/02/11/142347) 等の記事もあるので、混在はしない方が良いのでは？

Comment: Python3.6 の実行ファイルが見つからなければ Warning: Python 3.6 was not found on your system… がでてきて、インストールできそうならそうするかたずねてくるようなのですが、なぜそれがないのかが気になります。

pipenv --py
の結果
pipenv run python -c "import sys; print(sys.executable); print(sys.executable); print(sys.base_prefix)"
の結果などがあると参考になるかもしれません。

プロンプトの前に (base) が付いていますがこれがなにか分かりますか?（ご自分で把握していますか）

Comment: pipenv --pyなどの結果を追記しました。